# Botón para cambiar el color del background y texto

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en la cual necesito que haya un botón que me permita cambiar texto negro y background blanco o viceversa. ¿Alguien me podría ayudar con el script?

Éste es el código que tengo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() { /* Cualquier funcionalidad que queramos agregar a la página por medio de jQuery, debe ser incluida cuando el documento está listo para recibir acciones que modifiquen el DOM de la página. */
  $('.azul').click(function(event) { /* Seleccionamos el elemento que queremos que realice la función */
    $('body').css('background', '#08c'); /* La función a realizar añadir CSS al body previamente seleccionado */
  });
  $('.blanco').click(function(event) { /* Seleccionamos el elemento que queremos que realice la función */
    $('body').css('background', '#fff'); /* La función a realizar añadir CSS al body previamente seleccionado */
  });
});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
  margin: 0;
  /* Transition para el cambio de color */
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -ms-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
}

form {
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  background: #222;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

input[type="button"] {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tutorial 1 jQuery</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery (host Google) -->
  <script src="cambiarColor.js"></script>
  <!-- La función a realizar -->
</head>

<body>
  <header>Elige un color</header>
  <form>
    <input type="button" value="Azul" class="azul">
    <input type="button" value="Blanco" class="blanco">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Te anexo un ejemplo usando **jquery**, un poco de `css` y la función `toggleClass`, espero que te sea de ayuda, saludos.

```js
// Evento click del boton
$("#btnInvertirColores").click(function(){
  // Asigna o desasigna la clase black
  $("body").toggleClass('black');
});
```

```css
/* Clase con los colores que cambiara */
.black {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

/* Colores que tendra por default */
body {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  Texto de ejemplo
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <input type="button" id="btnInvertirColores" value="Invertir colores" />
</body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Holii, no entiendo nada. Vamos que estoy más perdido que un piojo en una peluca.

Comment: que duda tienes?